# NFC android manifest

Tags: android, android-manifest, nfc

I have added the following code to my manifest file:

```
 <activity
            android:name="com.example.123.scan"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TAG_DISCOVERED"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.scan" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
            </activity>
```

Every time I start my app.
I could not get the intent of NFC that I need to proceed.

```
public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
Toast.makeText(this, "onResume", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        String sss=getIntent().getAction();
        Toast.makeText(this,sss, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED.equals(sss)) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "NDEF", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            processIntent(getIntent());
        }
        if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED.equals(sss)) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "TAG", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            processIntent(getIntent());
        }
        if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED.equals(sss)) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "TECH", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            processIntent(getIntent());
        }
        }
```

Every time, it toasted `android.intent.action.scan` instead of the NFC intent. 
What is the problem?

Comment: Unless you explicitly send an intent named `android.intent.action.scan` to your activity, you should never receive any such intent. At least that's not any of the standard intents sent by Android.

Comment: Btw. what do you want to achieve with your code? What type of NFC tag do you want to detect? Do you want to also detect a specific NDEF message sent across Beam?

Answer (score 1):

I created an Android Library for easy NFC on android, check it out it might be an easy solution - [link](https://github.com/Rgghgh/NfcActivity)

Comment: Although this might be a good and useful library, unfortunately this answer is not a direct solution to the question stated.